# jQuery UI draggable attached to sortable then dropping on droppable element not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.16 and am having trouble dragging a draggable item through a sortable list and then dropping it on a droppable item.

Here is an example of my problem
     http://jsfiddle.net/9RURx/1/

The draggable item needs to be able to attach to the sortable list or be dropped on the droppable item.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing through sortable seems to make the list element lose its selector... not sure why, but the "accept" property doesn't work anymore

Quickest solution is to change accept to `accept: ".ui-draggable"'` see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/9RURx/3/

now maybe you don't want to use the built in class. You can add a class to the LIs you want to be dropable and refer to them that way. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/9RURx/4/

Comment: Weird, I guess it's still a bit buggy.